# How to compare two dates in Apex?

Tags: apex, batch

```
global class updatedbirthdate implements database.batchable<sobject>,database.stateful{

    // list for storing updated opportunity 
    public list<contact> conlist = new list<contact>(); 

    // start method of batch which collecting data 
    global database.querylocator start(database.batchablecontext bc){

   // fetching all accounts
    string str = 'select id,name,Birthdate,calculatedbdate__c from Contact';

    return database.getquerylocator(str);


    }

    // execute method of batch which will update the opportunity which have parent account
    global void  execute(database.batchablecontext bc,list<contact> scope){
            // iterating account and opportunity and apply logic
            for(contact con : scope){
               date bdate = con.Birthdate;
               system.debug('bdate'+bdate);
               date todaydate = system.Today();
                system.debug('todaydate=='+todaydate);
               if(bdate.day() > todaydate.day()){
                       con.calculatedbdate__c = todaydate;  
                         system.debug('caldate'+con.calculatedbdate__c);
               }

                conlist.add(con);
            }
            update conlist;
    }

     global void finish(database.batchablecontext bc){}

}
```

Comment: why you are comparing the day ?

Comment: Please update your post to contain some explanatory text of what you are trying to accomplish, and preferably a question.

Comment: You are essentially setting the calculated date to today for ANY Birthdate with a DAY > todays Day. You are forgetting the year, month, etc. To see if equals, I typically see if Day is equal then compare date.toStartOfMonth() equality. if both then the dates are equal.

Answer (score 6):

If you check the [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) documentation, you'll see that this code:

```
if (bdate.day() > todaydate.day()) {
    con.calculatedbdate__c = todaydate;
}
```

is comparing:

> day() Returns the day-of-month component of a Date

If you just want to set the date to today when the birthdate is after today, Apex lets you use the `Date` variables directly in comparisons like this:

```
if (bdate > todaydate) {
    con.calculatedbdate__c = todaydate;
}
```